# Bootstrap Multiselect with Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap Multiselect plugin (If unfamiliar here is a link https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)  however I want the box to be filled dynamically and so far it appears I can only have one.  For when the multi-select is working it has no data.

The code that I am trying to use to make the option a multiselect is this

```
<script id="example">
$('#chkveg').multiselect({
  enableClickableOptGroups: true
});
</script>
```

Now that code works in terms of making it look right just not show any data.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hightryan/axw0ntck/4/) is a fiddle of my code.

Answer (score 4):

Just call

```js
.multiselect('rebuild');
```

after `select` updated

I made some changes on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axw0ntck/5/)